# Voseo del subjuntivo del presente de verbos irregulares (ser, ir) en Chile

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo, argentina, chile, voseo

Espero encontrar algún chileno aquí que me pueda contestar la siguiente pregunta:

Se trata del subjuntivo del voseo, que se usa con bastante diferencia en las varias regiones voseantes. Ya sé que por ejemplo en el español rioplatense, normalmente se ocupa el subjuntivo del "tú", aunque esté con el pronombre "vos":

*"Vos me lo decís"* (voseo), pero *"No me lo digas!"* (tuteo).

El *digás* también lo he visto, tanto como *vayás, seás, pensés* (en vez de *vayas, seas, pienses*), pero me parece que es más informal.

A lo que más bien me refiero es como es eso en Chile. Sé que el voseo se ocupa también en el subjuntivo: *"No me mintái!", "Quiero que cerrí(s) la puerta!", "No te preocupí(s)."* Que yo sepa la s no se pronuncia realmente.

Ahora mi pregunta: Si hasta aquí es todo correcto lo que me he dado cuenta visitando aquellos países, ¿cuál es el subjuntivo informal que se usa con el voseo de los verbos *ser* e *ir* en Chile?

¿Existe algo así como *"no quiero que te vayái", "no seái triste", "no vayái a la playa hoy"*, etc.? Sé que el voseo en Chile es bastante informal, pero en esta pregunta me refiero solamente a eso. Sería más lógico si existieran esas formas, pero me parece que a pesar de todo con esos dos verbos no se usa el voseo en el subjuntivo, sea tan informal la situación como quiera.

Muchas gracias por cualquier información, me interesa todo lo que se refiera a ese asunto.

Que tengan buen día! (:

Comment: Hola hola, muchas gracias! Entonces a ver que más se le ocurre a la gente aquí (;

Answer (score 10):

En Chile el voseo verbal es generalizado para todos los modos y tiempos, incluido el subjuntivo y exceptuando el imperativo.

Los ejemplos que tú indicas (`"no quiero que te vayái", "no seái triste", "no vayái a la playa hoy"`) son totalmente normales y correctos.

Por regla general, el **presente** de las formas verbales voseantes chilenas se genera a partir del voseo español típico ("reverencial"), al que se le elimina la vocal anterior a la **i** y se relaja la **s** final casi hasta desaparecer. Esto implica ortografías variadas y dudosas. Por ejemplo:

> bailáis → bailái(h) → ¿Bailái bien? (Presente indicativo)
>
> compréis → comprí(h) → Quiero que me comprí cigarros. (Presente subjuntivo)

El **pretérito** voseante se forma simplemente relajando la -s final del voseo reverencial. Por ejemplo:

> bailabais → bailabai(h) → Bailabai bien (Pretérito indicativo)
>
> comprarais → Sería bueno que comprarai cigarros. (Pretérito subjuntivo)

Y por su parte el **futuro** siempre se forma con la forma voseante del verbo *ir*:

> ¿Adónde vai a comer? (dónde comerás)

Esta conjugación es marca de **informalidad y cercanía afectiva**. Se usa sobre todo **entre amigos**, aunque por imitación lo pueden usar los padres con los hijos y los superiores con los subordinados. No implica diferencia educacional, regional ni de estrato social. El rector de la universidad no lo usa en público, pero lo usa.

**En la persona singular** hay ustedeo, tuteo y voseo, dependiendo del nivel de formalidad.

**En la persona plural** no existe el voseo. Solo usamos la conjugación del  **ustedes**, sin ninguna variación.

> Quiero que le **pida** perdón. (Ustedeo: 2a persona singular formal y familiar)
>
> Quiero que le **pidas** perdón. (Tuteo: 2a persona singular informal)
>
> Quiero que le **pidái** perdón. (Voseo: 2a persona singular informal-afectivo)
>
> Quiero que le **pidan** perdón. (Ustedeo: 2a persona plural invariable)

Casi nunca usamos el pronombre **vos**, pues preferimos el **tú** cada vez que hay voseo verbal. El "vos" implica desdén o enojo, y puede sonar grosero:

> **Tú tenís** que creerme (voseo con tú, habitual y amistoso)
>
> **Vos tenís** que creerme (voseo con vos, poco frecuente y muy agresivo)

Por tratarse de una forma de hablar informal, los verbos que se conjugan de forma voseante son los más habituales y simples. Sonaría extraño decir *ojalá que reflexionarai*, porque el verbo "reflexionar" no forma parte del registro informal. En cambio, algunos verbos muy frecuentes tienen distintas formas voseantes:

> haber: ¿*hai* pensado? y ¿*habís* pensado? (¿has pensado?)
>
> ser: ¿*soi* casada? y ¿*erís* casada? (¿eres casada?)
>
> ir: no quiero que te *vai* y no quiero que te *vayái* (no quiero que te vayas)

Comment: Hola Rodrigo! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

La verdad es que ya conocía el 90% de lo que me has escrito, aunque sí fue muy interesante leer que el uso del voseo no implica diferencia educacional etc.! Las últimas formas _hai, habí(h), erí(h)_ y _soi_ también los he escuchado, aunque me parece que _hai_ tanto como _erí(h)_ se desarrollaron desde una analogía erronea (_has_ > _hai_ y _sos_ > _soi_). Lo más interesante fue que dices que "vayái" y "seái" sí se usan, porque recuerdo que eso se lo pregunté a un amigo de Santiago y me dijo que ustedes "tampoco hablaban _tan_ mal".